# 1D Time Series Similarity Measures

Tags: time-series, cluster-analysis

I am new to time series analysis. My work is mostly related to time series clustering. For that I am trying to find out some similarity measures for comparing two time series. I have studied about DTW and Constrained DTW. Are there any other similarity measures that are generally used for this task?

My dataset is large both in terms of dimensions(~100) and number of data points(~10000). I can not apply dimension reduction algorithms like PCA to reduce the dimensions as it is required in further work.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at distance measures such as Euclidean, Manhattan distance? You could also check dynamic time warping.